# Task Runner in Javascript

Tags: javascript, asynchronous, async-await, promise

I have a list of tasks and all these tasks need to be executed only after all the dependencies are resolved for each task. I am struggling to figure out a way to finish running all the tasks in optimal time.

```
// Each node is a async job, illustrated by setTimeout.
// A and C can run at the same time.
// D, needs to wait for A and C to be done.
// E needs to wait for A and D to be done.

function runTasks(tasks) {
 // run tasks
}

// Sample of tasks
var tasks = {
  'a': {
    job: function (finish) {
      setTimeout(function () {
        console.log('a done');
        finish();
      }, 500);
    },
  },
  'c': {
    job: function (finish) {
      setTimeout(function () {
        console.log('c done');
        finish();
      }, 200);
    },
    dependencies: [],
  },
  'd': {
    job: function (finish) {
      setTimeout(function () {
        console.log('d done');
        finish();
      }, 100);
    },
    dependencies: ['a','c'],
  },
  'e': {
    job: function (finish) {
      setTimeout(function () {
        console.log('e done');
        finish();
      }, 200);
    },
    dependencies: ['a', 'd'],
  },
};
```

Comment: _"A, B, and C can run at the same time."_ they do? Please share how, because afaik JavaScript is single threaded and can only run one thing at a time. - Also, you've tagged promises, but they're not being used.

Comment: Set a boolean for each task. Have the tasks that rely on other tasks run on an interval instead of a timeout and check if the booleans are set to true or not. So say boolA = false. When task A is done it sets boolA to true. Function C checks if both boolA and boolB are set to true. If not, it just doesn't run and continues on its interval loop. If they are, it runs and cancels its own interval afterwards so it doesn't run again. Keep going like that

Comment: The above code snippet is just a sample snippet and it can be modified to use asynchronous programming (async/await)

Comment: @evolutionxbox Well, yes and no. Although JS is single threaded, it does have callback functions. Meaning it just initiates them and continues running other tasks until the callback function "calls it back". Like a timeout is a callback function, so it'll just run other tasks until that timeout runs out and calls it back. Which can be a problem if those other tasks need to run after the timeout is finished. So ye, not running "at the same time", but definitely async

Comment: @icecub Using setInterval will not satisfy the requirement of 'optimal time', as the interval will induce latency.

Comment: @DaveMeehan True. That's why I made it a comment and not an answer. It's not a "solution". It's more of a workaround. If you have synced tasks relying an async tasks, you should just await the async tasks before initiating the synced ones. But that's beyond the scope of my knowledge, so I can't give an answer to that.

Comment: Is `tasks['a']` not having a `.dependencies` a mistake, or should `runTasks` be able to handle that?

Answer (score 1):

A simple recursive dependencies evaluation with caching of results will do. Use `Promise.all` to wait for all dependencies:

```
function runTasks(tasks) {
  const promises = {};
  function runTask(name) {
    const {dependencies, job} = tasks[name];
    return promises[name] ??= Promise.all(dependencies.map(runTask)).then(job);
  }
  return Promise.all(Object.keys(tasks).map(runTask));
}
```

Maybe use `Promise.allSettled` instead of `Promise.all` in the final `return` statement.

If you need to detect circular dependencies, you can use

```
…
  const circular = Promise.reject(new Error("circular dependency"));
  circular.catch(() => { /* ignore */ }); // prevent unhandled rejection
  function runTask(name) {
    const {dependencies, job} = tasks[name];
    if (promises[name] != null) return promises[name];
    promises[name] = circular;
    const jobArgs = Promise.all(dependencies.map(runTask));
    return promises[name] = jobArgs.then(job);
  }
…
```

Comment: I failed to understand how the circular dependencies detection works, can you explain it a little bit? Like you double assigned `promises[name] ` at the end, not sure how that is going to work...

Comment: @Joji First, `circular` (a rejected promise, that will propagate the error when you try to depend on it) is assigned as the value, then `dependencies.map(runTask)` is evaluated (which recursively traverses the dependencies and *may* come across the `circular` sentinel value), last the result promise is assigned as the value.

Comment: I still don't quite get it why there are two `promises[name] =` assignment at the end. 

Comment: @Joji I'v added an extra line now in which the recursion happens, does that help?

Answer (score 1):

You can start parallel promises which can be started.

1. Start all independent task first which has no dependencies
2. After completing independent tasks store in map/set
3. Then filter a new set of tasks using the complete set repeat steps.

```js
const wait = (ms, task) =>
  new Promise((resolve) =>
    setTimeout(() => {
      console.log(`${task} done`);
      resolve();
    }, ms)
  );

const tasks = {
  a: {
    job: () => wait(500, "A"),
    dependencies: [],
  },
  c: {
    job: () => wait(500, "C"),
    dependencies: [],
  },
  d: {
    job: () => wait(500, "D"),
    dependencies: ["a", "c"],
  },
  e: {
    job: () => wait(500, "E"),
    dependencies: ["a", "d"],
  },
};

const run = async () => {
  const completed = new Set();
  const keys = Object.keys(tasks);
  const runTasks = async (pendingTasks) => {
    const promises = pendingTasks.map((key) => tasks[key].job());
    await Promise.all(promises);
    pendingTasks.forEach((key) => completed.add(key));
  };

  const runner = async () => {
    const pendingTasks = keys.filter((key) => {
      if (!completed.has(key)) {
        const { dependencies } = tasks[key];
        return dependencies.every((dependency) => completed.has(dependency));
      }
      return false;
    });
    if (pendingTasks.length !== 0) {
      await runTasks(pendingTasks);
      return runner();
    }
  };

  await runner();
};

run();
```

Answer (score 0):

Something like this might be possible, I have changed the jobs to async methods and I keep track of them being resolved or not.

This code does not check for errors within the job or for circular dependencies.

Output of the script:

```
b done
a done
c done
e done
done
```

Code:

```
const runTasks = async tasks => {
  const taskArray = Object.entries(tasks)
  const resolved = {}

  while (taskArray.length) {
    const tasksToExecute = []
    for (const task of taskArray) {
      const dependencies = task[1].dependencies || []
      if (dependencies.length === 0 || dependencies.every(dependency => resolved[dependency] || false)) {
        tasksToExecute.push(task)
      }
    }

    await Promise.all(tasksToExecute.map(t => t[1].job()))
    tasksToExecute.forEach(t => {
      resolved[t[0]] = true
      taskArray.splice(taskArray.indexOf(t[0]), 1)
    })
  }
}

const tasks = {
  a: {
    job: async function () {
      return new Promise(resolve => {
        setTimeout(() => {
          console.log("a done")
          resolve()
        }, 500)
      })
    },
  },
  c: {
    job: async function () {
      return new Promise(resolve => {
        setTimeout(() => {
          console.log("c done")
          resolve()
        }, 200)
      })
    },
    dependencies: ["a", "b"],
  },
  b: {
    job: async function () {
      return new Promise(resolve => {
        setTimeout(() => {
          console.log("b done")
          resolve()
        }, 100)
      })
    },
    dependencies: [],
  },
  e: {
    job: async function () {
      return new Promise(resolve => {
        setTimeout(() => {
          console.log("e done")
          resolve()
        }, 200)
      })
    },
    dependencies: ["c", "b"],
  },
}

runTasks(tasks).then(r => console.log("done"))
```

Comment: Looks like this is not the optimal solution because a and b doesn't have any dependencies and can be initiated parallel

Comment: See updated answer

Comment: Observation: Using Promise.all means that all dependencies must complete before newly elligible tasks will commence.  For example, add a new task 'f' that is dependent on 'c', and it won't start until 'a' is complete.

Answer (score 0):

This uses `Promise.race` to treat tasks independently of others.  Using `Promise.all` is not optimal as it wait for all dependent tasks to complete before evaluating if another task can be started.

I think this is optimal timewise.  It might have higher processing overhead as all jobs are kept in a single object and might be better handled by moving jobs to a completed object to avoid reevaluating already completed tasks.

NB: This doesn't evaluate circular dependencies or that indeed, dependencies are tasks.

```js
"use strict";
class Job {
    constructor(getJobs, name, task) {
        this.getJobs = getJobs;
        this.name = name;
        this.task = task;
    }
    isWaiting() {
        return this.promise !== undefined;
    }
    isComplete() {
        return 'result' in this;
    }
    isBlocked() {
        return !(this.task.dependencies || []).map(name => this.getJobs()[name]).every(job => job.isComplete()) || false;
    }
    isElligible() {
        return !this.isWaiting() && !this.isComplete() && !this.isBlocked();
    }
}
async function runTasks(tasks) {
    const jobs = Object.entries(tasks)
        .reduce((acc, [name, task]) => {
        acc[name] = new Job(() => jobs, name, task);
        return acc;
    }, {});
    while (true) {
        Object.keys(jobs).forEach(name => {
            if (jobs[name].isElligible()) {
                console.log(`${name} elligible`);
                jobs[name].promise = new Promise(resolve => {
                    console.log(`${name} starting`);
                    jobs[name].task.job(resolve);
                }).then(res => {
                    jobs[name].result = res;
                    delete jobs[name].promise;
                });
            }
        });
        const pending = Object.values(jobs).filter(job => job.isWaiting());
        console.log('racing', pending.map(j => j.name));
        if (pending.length) {
            await Promise.race(pending.map(job => job.promise));
        }
        else {
            break;
        }
    }
}
var tasks = {
    'a': {
        job: function (finish) {
            setTimeout(function () {
                console.log('a done');
                finish();
            }, 500);
        },
    },
    'c': {
        job: function (finish) {
            setTimeout(function () {
                console.log('c done');
                finish();
            }, 200);
        },
        dependencies: [],
    },
    'd': {
        job: function (finish) {
            setTimeout(function () {
                console.log('d done');
                finish();
            }, 100);
        },
        dependencies: ['a', 'c'],
    },
    'e': {
        job: function (finish) {
            setTimeout(function () {
                console.log('e done');
                finish();
            }, 200);
        },
        dependencies: ['a', 'd'],
    },
    'f': {
        job: function (finish) {
            setTimeout(function () {
                console.log('f done');
                finish();
            }, 500);
        },
        dependencies: ['c'],
    },
};
runTasks(tasks).then(() => console.log('ALL done'));
```